# Calculating price ranges with LINQ and corresponding sale numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

to start things off I have a class which basically represents all the transactions for specific items, it's usually 100 items for which I have transactions. The class looks as following:

```
public class RawTransactions
    {
        public string SellerName { get; set; }
        public int FeedBackScore { get; set; }
        public int QuantityPurchased { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
        public double CurrentPrice { get; set; }
        public double SalePrice { get; set; }
        public string ItemID { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Based on this class and the transactions inside a list of this type I've created a function which basically takes smallest and largest sale price of any transaction that is present in the list and creates a 7 stage price range

```
private List<double> GetRangeForElements(double minPrice, double maxPrice)
   {
     double step = (maxPrice - minPrice) / 7.00d;
     return Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(i => minPrice + i * step).ToList();
   }
```

So for example if I pass $0 (smallest sale price) and $10 (largest sale price) it will create a list of 7 price range  like following:

```
0
1.5
3
4.5
6
7.5
9
10
```

This can be interpreted as:

```
0 - 1.5 price range
1.5 - 3 price range
3 - 4.5 price range
4.5 - 6 price range
6 - 7.5 price range

// and so on...
```

The usage is as following:

```
var ranges = GetRangeForElements(0,10); // Here I will have the ranges now
```

Now based on these ranges that were just created and the existing transactions that I have I need to determine following parameters:

- Price range
- How many sales specific ItemID has sales for a specific range
- How many sellers (based on SellerName property)  had sales for a specific price range
- How many sellers (again based on SellerName propert) DIDN'T had sales for a specific price range

I'm not really sure how can I now combine all this data to get these parameters using LINQ? Can someone help me out with this?

P.S. guys the transactions of all items are stored in a List like following:

```
var allItemsTransactions = new List<ProductResearchRawTransactions>();
```

P.S. guys this is the existing solution that I have, but it's giving me completely wrong results:

```
var priceRanges = ranges.Select(r => new PriceRangeGraph
                {
                    Price = Math.Round(r, 2),
                    Sales = allItemsTransactions.Where(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(y => y >= x.SalePrice) == r).Sum(x => x.QuantityPurchased),
                    SuccessfulSellers = allItemsTransactions.Where(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(y => y >= x.SalePrice) == r).GroupBy(x => new { x.SellerName, x.QuantityPurchased }).Where(x => x.Key.QuantityPurchased > 0).Select(x => x.Key.SellerName).Count(),
                    UnSuccessfulSellers = allItemsTransactions.Where(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(y => y >= x.SalePrice) == r).GroupBy(x => new { x.SellerName, x.QuantityPurchased }).Where(x => x.Key.QuantityPurchased == 0).Select(x => x.Key.SellerName).Count(),
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: You know that SO is not free coding service ?

Comment: @Selvin No I wasn't looking for that, I had a soloution that I have tried, I'm posting it now, but it gives me completely wrong results

Comment: @Selvin I've posted the initial solution that I have

Comment: `realranges.Select(r=>new {r, items = allItemsTransactions.Select(t=>t.SalePrice >= r.Item1 && t.SalePrice < r.Item2).ToDictionary(a=>a.r, a.items)` where `realranges` is `Tuple<double, double>` ... i didn't test it but you need something like this ...

Comment: @Selvin Not sure what should I do next with the tuple ?: D

Comment: One problem with your code is you are not testing for being within a range, but only greater than the lowest part of the range. You need to get both the high and low of each range, such as `var realRanges = ranges.Zip(ranges.Skip(1), (low,high) => (low,high));`

Comment: Of course, you could also update your `GetRange` method to return the low and high of each range in some class. BTW, which range does e.g. `1.5` belong to?

Comment: Your `PriceRangeGraph` class doesn't seem to match your requirements: what does "based on SellerName property" actually mean?

Comment: @NetMage Erm, based on SellerName property as in unique identifier within all transactions that I have for all items, if this makes sense what I just said? xD